# How can I add a dash to separate the string when is too long in SQL Server? I need to write the script, not hardcoding it...thanks

Tags: sql-server, scripting

I need to rename my records..so the data the I have today is like:

```
user.apple
user.applebanana 
user.applegrapes
user.applegrapeskiwi
```

I want:

```
user.apple,
user.apple-banana,
user.apple-grapes,
user.apple-grapes-kiwi
```

and so on...

I need to add a dash when the second string is too big...

I'm newbie in SQL, I have tried a substring but is not this. It would be easier if I could use a `replace()` function, but I'm not supposed to hardcode... :(

Comment: How do *you* know when one word starts and ends? Why not `'appleba-nana'`?

Comment: well, the second word starts always after the "." dot. and the word "apple" is my case is kind of fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second word is **always** `'apple'` and is **always** prefixed with `.` then you could use `STUFF` to inject the character:

```
SELECT YourColumn,
       CASE LEN(YourColumn) WHEN CHARINDEX('.',YourColumn) + 5 THEN YourColumn
                            ELSE STUFF(YourColumn, CHARINDEX('.',YourColumn)+6,0,'-') END
FROM (VALUES('user.apple'),
            ('user.applebanana'),
            ('user.applegrape'),
            ('operator.apple'),
            ('operator.applekiwi'))V(YourColumn);
```

The `CASE` expression is there, as otherwise you'd have `'user.apple-'`.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be7bce12a6da3e790d5a972b2a203b80)

Comment: Please do considering marking the answer as the solution if it did, @Tavi . It shows your appreciation, let's future users know the answer was helpful, let's future readers know that the question has been answered and you get reputation; which is really important for getting those early [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Thanks!

Comment: sorry@Larnu...I'm also still learning how to ask a question here...

Comment: No worries, @Tavi :)

Comment: @ Larnu- another question if you don'y mind....what if I don't want to hard code the values? Is that a way?

Comment: I refer to my original comment under your question , @Tavi .